# Get array output in puppet ERB from hiera

Tags: puppet, ruby, hiera, erb

I have a array defined in the following format in hiera.

```
 master_servers:
  - "stage-01.com"
  - "stage-02.com"
```

I am trying to populate the config file with ERB in the following format

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["stage-01.com", "stage-02.com" ]

I tried the following in ERB, but the array comes off as a single string.

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: <%= scope['::profiles::xxx::master_servers'] %>
```

The `profiles::xxx::master_servers` is correctly doing the hiera lookups.

How can I correct my ERB?

Comment: You can use `to_json` from stdlib.

Comment: @jordanm Does this work with puppet ERB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the comment from `jordanm` - you can use the `to_json` function from the `puppetlabs-stdlib` module - [source](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#to_json).

In your Puppet manifest:

```
class profiles::xxx(
  $master_servers,
) {
  $master_servers_json = to_json($master_servers)
  ...
}
```

In your ERB:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: <%= scope['::profiles::xxx::master_servers_json'] %>
```